# Wicket 6: Including Javascript files to head with script tag

Tags: java, wicket

I guess the title is very self descriptive but here it goes nonetheless: I have a Panel where I would like to add multiple script tags with javascript files from my system.

I tried the following but script tags still not showing.

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
  super.renderHead(response);
  for(String path : arrayOfJsFiles){
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem
        .forReference(new PackageResourceReference(getClass(),
                path)));
  }
```

}

Comment: Where are the javascript files located?

Comment: @DomasPoliakas locally, under a JS folder.

Comment: Do you mean the webapp/js folder?

Comment: @DomasPoliakas I have some in a webapp/js folder and some others outside of the webapp but still locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the exact file hierarchy of your project I can't tell what exactly could the issue be, but I can give you some pointers.

Firstly, if I understand correctly, the javascript files are not in the same package as the class in which the code you supplied is executed. That is not quite what the `PackageResourceReference` expects. **Package** resource is a resource that is in the **package** of the file; so if you have a class com/custom/MyClass.java, your package resources should be also be located in the same folder, i.e. com/custom/some-javascript.js

For that reason in the constructor [`PackageResourceReference#PackageResourceReference(Class, String)`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/request/resource/PackageResourceReference.html#PackageResourceReference%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) you supply 2 things: the **scope** and the **name**. The scope is a class that is in the same package as the resources, the name is simply the name of the file, rather than the path to the file; the path is defined by the scope.

I'm not sure if it is the best approach, but when I need to use global resources, I don't actually ever construct a `ResourceReference`, but instead use 
`JavaScriptHeaderItem.forUrl("./js/some-javascript.js")` and such to render the resources (./js/ is the webapp/js/ folder).

However, I'm not sure if that is a correct way to deal with resources. I highly recommend reading [this](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/resources.html), as it covers resources quite well and could help you with your problem.